# Conditional stacking of highchart columns

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

I'm trying to create an `columnchart` using `highcharts`. The intent is for 2 of the series to be stacked on top of each other, and the third to be placed besides them.

My sample CSV file looks like this:

```
Datoer,01/2013,02/2013,03/2013,04/2013
Disk - Freespace,800,1000,1243,1387
Disk - Allokeret,1000,1200,1456,1689
Tape Forbrug,5241,5942,6752,7210
```

The code looks like the following:

```
$(document)
  .ready(function () {


  var graph = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'column'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Imaginært Diskforbrug'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Gigabyte'
      },
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -100,
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 20,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
      borderColor: '#CCC',
      borderWidth: 1,
      shadow: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
        }
      }
    },
    series: []
  };

  $.get('data.txt', function (data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
      var items = line.split(',');

      // header line containes categories
      if(lineNo == 0) {
        $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
          if(itemNo > 0) graph.xAxis.categories.push(item);
        });
      }

      // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
      else {
        var series = {
          data: []

        };
        $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
          if(itemNo == 0) {
            series.name = item;
          } else {
            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
          }
        });

        graph.series.push(series);
      }

    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(graph);
  });


});
```

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to differentiate on which series are stacked, and which are not. I would like my fourth line in the CSV file to not be stacked with the 2 other (number 2 and 3 in the file), but to instead appear just beside them.

It seems that my only option for defining whether the columns are stacked are in the `plotOptions`, but this leave me no choice to separate the stacking of series.

Answer (score 0):

Is this, what are you looking for?

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.stack

```
jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/stack/
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to familiar with preprocessing CSV data 
http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing